# grep on some files

Tags: unix, grep

I want to find all files with extension x in all sub folders containing string s, how do I do this?

grep -nr s .*.x ?????

Dirk

Comment: Sorry I wasn't 100% accurate, I did actually want the contents of the files, I have worked out <grep -nr s --include=*x .>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU find

```
find . -iname "*.x" -type f -exec grep -l "s" {} +;
```

If you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
Dir["/path/**/*.x"].each do |file|
  if test(?f,file)
   open(file).each do |line|
     if line[/s/]
       puts "file: #{file}"
       break
     end
   end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first *find* the *.x files, and then search the string you are interested in with *grep*:

```
$ find directory -name "*.x" -exec grep -Hn s {} \;
```

- `-name "*.x"` searches recursively every file sufixed with *x*.
- `-exec grep ... {} \;` searchs the *s* string for each encountered file.
- `-H` is recommended, since you wouldn't know which file matched the expression.